# Azure Pipelines yml help - understanding my yml file and why it isn't deploying

Tags: .net, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

I am really new to Azure DevOps and am trying to configure Azure pipelines for my project.

Currently my .yml file looks like this:

```
trigger:
- my-test-branch

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet test $(buildConfiguration)'
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '**/*Tests/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet publish $(buildConfiguration)'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: True
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: True

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'publish artifacts'
  inputs: 
    pathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
```

I have managed to pull this together from various sources and now works as a successful build pipeline in that it builds my project, runs the NUnit tests and either passes or fails based on this. I have a few questions about this:

1. What is the `PublishBuildArtifacts` task for? I thought that this part of the file was the continuous delivery part and would automatically publish my code to my web app but it seems that this is not happening and I realised I don't really understand what it means to "Publish Build Artifacts" - explanations in Azure documentation don't really shed much light on it for me either.
2. Following on from 1., how can I configure continuous delivery? I have a web app and would like my code to automatically deploy there if the tests pass.
3. What is the effect of the `trigger` branch? To clarify, I will explain the structure of my project: I have the `master` branch, a `develop` branch (branching off master) and `my-test-branch` branching off develop. If I want code to automatically deploy to `develop` from `my-test-branch` (if all tests pass), is there a way of configuring this? Or does it have to be done as a pull request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PublishBuildArtifacts task is just publishing any artifacts your create in your build as artifacts of the build. This just means that they are available in the artifacts tab of the build info and other builds or release can consume these artifacts if they wish, it has nothing to do with releasing to Azure.

If you want to do continuous delivery then you want to start looking at creating a release that uses the output of your build and pushes it out to Azure (or wherever else you want it to go). You can either look at using [multi-stage YAML pipelines](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/whats-new-with-azure-pipelines/) to create releases in YAML, which are in preview, or you can look at the older visual [release pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops).

The trigger you list means that any commits to that branch will cause this pipeline to run, but any commits to master or develop will not.